# I want to load wxwidgets from an xml string in memory.

Tags: wxwidgets

Is there a way to load wxwidgets from an in memory xrc string, or do I have to save it to a temporary file and load that?

Comment: What do you call "wxwidgets"? Controls? Can you post an example of such xrc string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it using [wxFileSystem](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_system.html). Your code should do something like this:

```
#include <wx/filesys.h>

wxFileSystem::AddHandler(new wxMemoryFSHandler);
wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFile("myxrc", actual_xrc.utf8_str(), actual_xrc.utf8_length());
wxXmlResource::Get()->Load("memory:myxrc");
```

This is the technique used by `wxrc` utility to embed XRC into your program.